# python element tree xml parsing

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am using Python element tree to parse xml file

lets say i have an xml file like this ..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello this is first paragraph </p>
    <p> hello this is second paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any way i can extract the body with the p tags intact like

```
desired= "<p>hello this is first paragraph </p> <p> hello this is second paragraph</p>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does the trick.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(doc)  # doc is a string containing the example file
body = root.find('body')
desired = ' '.join([ET.tostring(c).strip() for c in body.getchildren()])
```

Now:

```
>>> desired
'<p>hello this is first paragraph </p> <p> hello this is second paragraph</p>'
```

Comment: also its not just p tags there can be any like <b> tags <i> tags any suggestions ...

Comment: That will pull out any of the body's children, regardless of the tag type. I think it may be confusing that I used `p` in my code. That has nothing to do with the `<p>` tag, and I will change the code to be clear. This solution will not work, however, when the body has text that is not inside a child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lxml library, [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)

So, this code will help you.

```
import lxml.html

htmltree = lxml.html.parse('''
<html>
<head>
<title>Example page</title>
</head>
 <body>
<p>hello this is first paragraph </p>
<p> hello this is second paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>''')
p_tags = htmltree.xpath('//p')
p_content = [p.text_content() for p in p_tags]

print p_content
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way to @DavidAlber, where the children could easily be selected:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("example.xml")
body = tree.findall("/body/p")

result = []
for elem in body:
     result.append(ElementTree.tostring(elem).strip())

print " ".join(result)
```